# How to add a footnote using Apache POI?

Tags: java, apache

I'm using XWPF to create a docx document. I didn't find out how to add a footnote. Can anyone help?

Comment: Try this - http://www.concretepage.com/apache-api/apache-poi-xwpf-write-ms-word-docx-header-footer-body-paragraph-example

Comment: That's not what I need. That's about header and footer. I need to write a footnote.